# window.open + Opening content in 2 tabs

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I'm using angular js and javascript in my application.And here , when I click `<a>` tag it call a method in angular controller ,which has  `$window.open();`.**Every time I click it content open in 2 tabs**.What is the reason for that? Please help me out.

**HTML**

```
 <li><a href="#" id="test_home" ng-click="test_home()">Test Click</a></li>
```

**Angular controller**

```
controllers.controller('LogoutCtrl', ['$scope', '$location','$cookieStore','$rootScope','$window',
    function($scope, $location,$cookieStore,$rootScope ,$window) {

        $scope.test_home = function () {
            $window.open('www.yahoo.com'); 
         };             
    }
    ]);
```

Comment: Run browser in private mode and check it one more time. Maybe you have installed some plugin to browser.

Answer (score 0):

Try using preventDefault:

```
$scope.test_home = function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $window.open('www.yahoo.com'); 
         };
```

Or, use `return false;`

Answer (score 0):

Nothing in common with `$window.open`, maybe some other event listener is bind to `#test_home` or some browser plugin is responsible for it.

Short example on jsfiddle shows that method will open only one window / tab.

```
angular.module('windowOpen', []).controller('open', function ($scope, $window) {
    $scope.openMe = function () {
        $window.open('http://google.com/');
    };
});
```

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/krzysztof_safjanowski/AKB4c/